# Resources on dice rolling for Rolisteam

Tags: dice, shadowrun-sr4, rolisteam

Where can I find reliable instructions as to how dice rolling programming works with Rolisteam **specifically** (I use 1.8.2)?

All I can find is about DiceParser (which seems to be the base code used in Rolisteam) but the commands provided aren't working for me. Even if I copy and paste the examples for DiceParser in Rolisteam, it isn't working (and yes, I add the "!" at the beginning).

Comment: I am correct to assume you've looked at their very own [tutorial](https://rolisteam.org/tutorial01.html), [Discord bot](https://rolisteam.org/discord.html) and their [complete dice command documentation](https://github.com/Rolisteam/DiceParser/blob/master/HelpMe.md), all found on [their website](https://rolisteam.org)? We can't tell you what you haven't done without knowing what you have done, though certainly we can make educated guesses. The first step is likely going to be reproducing whatever error(s) you're having

Comment: At least for that last one, it's the DiceParser documentation being provided, which they say the commands for do not work. I am not familiar with the platform myself.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have actual examples of what you have tried and what happened, or didn't happen. Specific information makes it way easier to help you with your problem.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you have accidentally created two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way you will be able to comment on your own question.